# Controller not working in mvc 4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller named as UserController and in that only Index action is being called 
another action added like as '**home action**' is not being called  and **either calling actionresult/string or returning view**

I am getting this error

**while running at Google  Chrome**

> {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   /user/home'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the
>   controller named 'home'."}

**And running at Mozilla Firefox**

> Whoops! The page could not be found. Try giving it another chance
>   below.

**Here is my whole Controller Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Mvc4Application1.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /User/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult AddPlace()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult UpdatePlace()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult DeletePlace()
        {
            return View();
        } 
    }
}
```

**Here is RouteConfig.cs file**

```
 routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
 defaults: new 
{ controller = "Home", action = "Index",
  id=UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Comment: Show please code, where redirect is going?

Comment: What's your routing code looking like?

Comment: Have you not got a HomeController? This is where MVC will look by default. The url for the UserController would be /user.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Here are the following things you need to cross check*

- Inheriting controller from Controller and not from ApiController
- Make sure Routeconfig has proper Maproute

  **Else you need to rename the controller** [*sounds weird but it might help*]

and **use ActionResult as return datatype**

Comment: Darndest thing, I had the same problem and renamed the controller and it forked for me to.  Does anyone have any idea why it just didn't like certain names? I tried renaming it back to the old name and it was still busted.

Answer (score 14):

A method in a Controller that returns a `string` will **not** be routable. It **must** return an `ActionResult` (or one of it's derived classes).

Change it to:

```
public ActionResult Home()
{
    return View("Hello from home");
}
```

Then in your Views/Home folder, add a view called Home that has something like:

```
@model string

<p>@Model</p>
```

Comment: true that, I did not saw the string return! This is highly likely to be the issue if the route is pointing to the controller

Answer (score 5):

Things to consider:

- Make sure you're inheriting your controller from Controller and not from ApiController
- Make sure your routes are OK
- From the comments, also make sure if your controller is not Home, that User is default on your route

These are fairly simple things, but I've clicked OK several times just to realize that I selected ApiController on Asp .NET MVC 4!

Example route would be:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "User", action = "home", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

Please note that this will use UserController as default and home as the default view, although, I would recommend naming home to Index as it's more common.

If is not any of these, please post your whole controller so we can get a further look of it!

Hope I can help!

Answer (score 0):

see my own question ! and my own reply
you just need to add an additional maproute in routeconfig file in order to have that controller name

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "WhateverName" ,
                url: "ProblematicControllerName/{action}/{id}" ,
                defaults: new { controller = "user" , action = "anyaction" , id = UrlParameter.Optional }


            );
```

[Why I can't name a MVC .net controller session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738281/why-i-cant-name-a-mvc-net-controller-sesion?noredirect=1#comment51413207_31738281)

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 MVC/WebAPI Projects in my solution. Somehow, one gained a project reference to the other and it caused it to break only the HelpController and cause Documentation.xml exceptions.

Removing this reference solved the issue. I guess this is why you should just press CTRL+. and Enter without looking.