# Why I can't name a MVC .net controller session?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is pretty explicit but I will explain:

I am adding the following controller  siteblahblah/sesion/inicio/ and it says my resource don't exist!

So I used a mapped route like this and it worked out, but why? Sesion name controller gives problems? Am I confusing MVC framework in a strange way?

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "sesion" ,
                url: "Sesion/{action}/{id}" ,
                defaults: new { controller = "Sesion" , action = "Inicio" , id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

**EDIT:UPDATE**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyMVCapp.Controllers
{
    public class SesionController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /sesion/

        public ActionResult Inicio()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

By the way there's no typos! sesion is the spanish word for session so I don't want to name session in English for my "sesion" for my spanish users.

Comment: Can you give us the definition of your controller too ?

Comment: Could you check the spelling of session in the route and in the controller name? There seem to be typos in the post

Comment: So, you show us the code that works? Could you show us what _doesn't_ work?

Comment: yep, just remove the route named "sesion" from routeconfig file and it will crash.You will not reach the view  localhost/sesion/inicio getting the error!

Comment: i'v try your code,it's ok;do you have default route?

Comment: yes i do have a default route like this routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Defaultt" ,
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}" ,
                defaults: new { controller = "Inicio" , action = "Bienvenida" , id = UrlParameter.Optional });

Comment: Can you show us the error that you were getting before you modified your MapRoute?

Answer (score -1):

You can use like this,

```
string actionName = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
string controllerName = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.